# Pattern comparison between two columns in DB2

Tags: db2

I have two columns colA, colb in DB2.

```
colA contains string - @+1 XAT59001XBY999$
colB has 2 ROWS containing- XAT59001 and XBY999
```

I want to check whether colA contains colB data.

Comment: A column can contain **value**, but not **rows**. Can you rewrite your question providing your data in a table form and the result desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `INSTR` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE INSTR(colA, colB) > 0;
```

You may also use `LIKE` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE colA LIKE '%' || colB || '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Self join the table with the `Like` condition

```
  SELECT distinct t1.colA,t1.colB
    FROM TestTable t1
    join TestTable t2 on t1.colA LIKE '%' || t2.colB || '%';
```